# what does 0 indicate in socket() system call?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

what 0 indicates in following line?
what are other flags i can use?

```
server = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have likely said, the third argument to `socket` is generally an `int` indicating the protocol.  `0` indicates that the caller does not want to specify the protocol and will leave it up to the service provider.

Other than zero, another common one is `IPPROTO_TCP`.

Full details can be found on the man page using `man 2 socket` on your machine or visiting [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket).

Answer (score 3):

From the man pages of socket:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

> The  protocol  specifies  a 
>   particular  protocol  to be used with
>   the socket.  Normally **only a single**
>   protocol
>          exists to support a particular socket type within a given protocol
>   family, in which case protocol can be
>   speci‐
>          fied  as **0**.  However, it is possible that many protocols may
>   exist, in which case a particular
>   protocol must be
>          specified in this manner.  The protocol number to use is specific to
>   the “communication domain” in which
>   commu‐
>          nication  is to take place; see protocols(5).  See getprotoent(3) on
>   how to map protocol name strings to
>   proto‐
>          col numbers.

Answer (score -3):

The best thing to do here is read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket). This document states that the third parameter is the protocol, which in this case is SOCK_STREAM but can be others.

Comment: SOCK_STREAM is for the second parameter, type, not the third.